# Can view pic in URL - but shows broken when displaying?

Tags: html

I am trying to insert an image on my site.

http://canarywharfian.co.uk/pages/kkkk/

As you can see it's showing as broken. However, when you click on it, it loads. I am confused why does it not show, if its loads if you click on it?

```
<a href="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/sample-2.jpg">
<img src="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/thumb2_trading.jpg border="0" class="firstimgbord" height="162" width="90"></a>
```

Comment: The href in the anchor tag and img src are pointing at different images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a closing `"` in your image `src` tag:

```
<img src="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/thumb2_trading.jpg" border="0" class="firstimgbord" height="162" width="90"></a>

                                                            ^
```

Comment: Glad to help buddy. Happy coding !